# "Debunking Scandinavian Envy"

Tags: social-welfare, denmark

On Greg Mankiw's blog, he posted the following entry, titled "Debunking Scandinavian Envy".

http://gregmankiw.blogspot.com/2016/08/debunking-scandinavia-envy.html

> Fact of the day: "Danish-Americans have a measured living standard about 55 percent higher than the Danes in Denmark. Swedish-Americans have a living standard 53 percent higher than the Swedes, and Finnish-Americans have a living standard 59 percent higher than those back in Finland."

However, I don't really see how this debunks anything. Consider e.g. these Danish-Americans, who have moved to the United States - they are presumably wealthy white collar workers (or even possibly succesful artists), since these are the kind of people who could afford relocating to the US in the first place, and so the comparison is flawed to begin with: obviously a wealthy person is going to have a higher living standard compared to the average Dane, regardless of whether they live in Denmark or the US. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: `they are presumably wealthy white collar workers (or even possibly succesful artists),` I have an issue with this assumption. I understand your idea that is unlikely that Scandinavian working population has its basic needs covered and so the only way to prompt emigration is to offer better conditions that what they have at home (and in the USA, that means mostly pay because welfare is far worse). But you write that as granted, so this makes the question kind of circular (you already have posted *your opinion* of what is happening and why Greg Mankiw's is wrong).

Comment: I think it would be better if you asked for, say, studies and polls about emigration from Scandinavia to the USA (if you cannot find them yourself in the Internet). If you already have them and have reached a conclusion and you just want to say that Greg Mankiw's idea is wrong, then the best place for such a rebuttal should probably be Greg Mankiw's site.

Comment: Obviously what I am asking is whether I am wrong about my assumption of the wealth of these Danish-Americans. So, yes, if you could point me to reports that detail, say, the income level (*prior to leaving*) of emigrates from Scandinavia to the US, then that'd probably help me reaching a conclusion.

Comment: Questions in the form "Is this statement true"? are the main focus of https://skeptics.stackexchange.com. Your question might get more attention over there. It doesn't fit well here because it's only tangentially related to politics.

Comment: What is scandinavian envy? Is that an established  term?

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> they are presumably wealthy white collar workers (or even possibly succesful artists), since these are the kind of people who could afford relocating to the US in the first place, and so the comparison is flawed to begin with

From the Swedish Americans [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_Americans) page:

> Swedish Americans (Swedish: Svenskamerikaner) are an American ethnic group of people who have ancestral roots from Sweden. They primarily include the 1.2 million Swedish immigrants during 1885–1915 and their descendants.

From the Danish Americans [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Americans) page:

> Between 1820 and 1990 there was a population of 375,000 Danes; a vast majority of whom emigrated between 1860 and 1930 The greatest Danish emigration occurred in 1882 when 11,618 Danes settled in the United States.

These are not a handful of modern Danes or Swedes who switched countries recently.  The typical Swedish or Danish American is descended from people who have lived in the United States for over a century.  And the original immigrants tended to be comparatively poor, not white collar workers or artists.  You can of course find exceptions, but that's the typical story.

Comment: B-b-bbut t-that would mean America offers more advancement opportunity than the socialist paradises in northern Europe...